# When can "che" replace "perché" in a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Consider *muoviti, che è tardi* and *muoviti, perché è tardi*. Which one is preferred? Why?

Answer (score 13):

First of all, *ché*, not *che*, is the shortened form of *perché*. So, you could use any of them because they are literally the [same thing](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/che/).
Grammatica Italiana di Serianni reads as follows:

> Nell'italiano di registro colloquiale antico e moderno, ma con larghissime attestazioni anche letterarie, si ricorre spesso a *ché* per collegare una dipendente a una subordinata <...> Abbastanza spesso si istituisce tra le due proposizioni un evidente rapporto causale: *copritevi, ché fa freddo*...

I should note that, although [Modern Italian Grammar](http://books.google.se/books?id=eabbAAAAQBAJ) (p.279) defines *ché* "rather old-fashioned but still used in the written texts," it's actually quite common.

Comment: Actually *perché* is a compound of *per* + *che*; I suspect that the accented form is a retroformation.

Comment: @egreg Sure, perché is a compound; any etymological dictionary confirms that. But modern Italian dictionaries in the entry for *ché* usually say "aferesi di perché", probably to distinguish between *che* and *ché*

Answer (score 3):

As *Lo Zingarelli 2013* says, *che* is used to introduce different kind of subordinate clauses. In particular, it introduces a [causal clause](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposizione_causale) when the verb is using the indicative or the subjunctive mood.

> Vai a dormire che è tardi.

> Andiamo, che è tardi.

> [image: screenshot]

In those sentences, I would use *che*, not *perché*.

At the same time, in the following sentences I would not replace *perché* with *che*, even though *perché* introduces a causal clause with the verb in the indicative or subjunctive mood too.

> Non l'ho comprato perché non mi piaceva.

> Non sono venuto perché s'era fatto tardi.

Comment: Can you add a reference for the image?

Comment: Oh, that is _Lo Zingarelli 2013_; I am trying to find an online version.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Does *Lo Zingarelli* have an entry for *ché* as well? Because the dictionary at Sapere.it, based on [Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=che%202), gives the very same example [*copriti ché fa freddo*](http://www.sapere.it/sapere/dizionari/dizionari/Italiano/C/CH/ch%C3%A9.html?q_search=) and [*copriti che fa freddo*](http://www.sapere.it/sapere/dizionari/dizionari/Italiano/C/CH/che2.html?q_search=)

Comment: @I.M. _Lo Zingarelli Minore_ (_ed. Terzo millennio_, 2001) **does** have an entry for _ché_: “**ché cong.** Perché. (V. nota d’uso ACCENTO)”

Comment: The note of use _ACCENTO_ explicitly contrasts “**ché** (= _perché_, cong.)” with “**che** (pron. rel. o cong.)”